# Nested Do Loops in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, do-loops

I'm trying to figure out how to nest these loops so that I can generate some multilevel data. I keep getting an error, though. I'm really new to SAS so I'm struggling to figure out how to fix this. Thanks for any help!

```
%macro MLM;
data x;
call streaminit(525600);
do rep=1 to 1000;
 
    %do a=1 %to 4;
    %if &a=1 %then %do; %let N=100; %end;
    %if &a=2 %then %do; %let N=250; %end;
    %if &a=3 %then %do; %let N=500; %end;
    %if &a=4 %then %do; %let N=1000; %end;

        do J=1 to &N;
        u0= RAND('NORMAL',0,1);
        w1= RAND('BERNOULLI',.5);
         
            do I=1 to (10000/&N);
    
                %do b = 1 %to 5;
                %if &b=1 %then %do; %let e=RAND('NORMAL',0,1); %end;
                %if &b=2 %then %do; %let e=RAND('UNIFORM'); %end;
                %if &b=3 %then %do; %let e=RAND('CHISQUARE', &N-1); %end;
                %if &b=4 %then %do; %let e=RAND('LOGNORMAL'); %end;
                %if &b=5 %then %do; %let e=RAND('BETA',1,1); %end;

                x1= RAND('BERNOULLI',.5);
                b0 = 2.5+ 1*w1+u0;
                b1 = 0.15;
                y=b0+b1*x1+&e;
                output; 
                %end; 
            end;
        end; 
    %end;
end; 
%mend MLM; run; %MLM; run;
```

I want to run 1000 simulations, with 4 sample sizes (a, N), then generate N samples, during which I want to simulate 5 different error distributions. So, in the end, I should get 1000x4x5 total samples.

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you provide any more information about what the error says?

From an initial look at the code - `ëNORMALí` looks incorrect

Comment: haha that's definitely some sort of weird copy error, I don't know how I missed that. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Why the macro logic at all? It seems unneccesary but want to check before I post a non macro solution.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this as a typo.  The code actually works as expected once the "smart quotes" were fixed.  The number expected is not quite right though - but that's not related to a code error, it's just wrong. (You get 1000x4x10000x5.  Any chance you're also running out of disk with the 200 million rows?  It's not insanely large, but if your disk is small...)

Comment: Also note @therussman this wasn't a "weird copy error" - you have smart quotes in your code, probably pasted from Outlook or Word or something.  The quotes that are curvy instead of 'single quotes' that are just straight lines.  Only the "real" quotes will work!

Comment: @Joe, you're definitely right, the 1000*4*5 is certainly off for how many I'm expecting. Redoing the math, I should get 1000*(100+250+500+1000)*5, at least based on how I'm reading it? What am I missing?

Comment: You're forgetting the  `10000/N` inner loop.  It ends up being 1000x4x10000x5, the N "addition" doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the macro logic and simplifying it slightly gets you this, which seems to work correctly to me. Note I simplified the N to ensure it runs quickly. Note that I'm not verify the logic, assuming that's correct on your side.

```
    data x;
        call streaminit(525600);

        do rep=1 to 5;

            do a=1 to 4;

                if a=1 then
                    N=100;
                else if a=2 then
                    N=250;
                else if a=3 then
                    N=500;
                else if a=4 then
                    N=1000;

                do J=1 to N;
                    u0=RAND('NORMAL', 0, 1);
                    w1=RAND('BERNOULLI', .5);

                    do I=1 to (2000/N);

                        do b=1 to 5;

                            if b=1 then
                                e=RAND('NORMAL', 0, 1);
                            else if b=2 then
                                e=RAND('UNIFORM');
                            else if b=3 then
                                e=RAND('CHISQUARE', N-1);
                            else if b=4 then
                                e=RAND('LOGNORMAL');
                            else if b=5 then
                                e=RAND('BETA', 1, 1);
                                
                                
                            x1=RAND('BERNOULLI', .5);
                            b0=2.5+ 1*w1+u0;
                            b1=0.15;
                            y=b0+b1*x1+e;
                            output;
                        end;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    run;
```